# Sequences and Series: Find the value for x such that series (ln x)^n is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm having difficulty with this problem on my homework.

"Find the value of x such that series $(\ln x)^n$ converges."

I've tried taking the natural log, so it would be $n \ln(\ln x)$ then $(\ln(\ln x))/(1/n)$ for lhospitals rule. But I'm not fairing to well, anyone have any hints on what to do or things that I might be doing wrong with this approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Let $y = \ln x$.  Can you figure out for which values of $y$ the series $y^n$ converges?

Comment: If y = ln x, then ln x would have to be -1 < r < 1 as its geometric, thats genius, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We essentially are asking for which $x$ does

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \ln(x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty r^n$$

converge, where $r = \ln(x)$. With this in mind, we visibly have a geometric series of ratio $r = \ln(x)$. Thus, since we require $|r| < 1$ for such series to converge, we need $x$ such that

$$|\ln(x)| < 1 \iff -1 < \ln(x) < 1 \iff \frac 1 e < x < e$$

Comment: Do you mean $\frac1e\lt x\lt e$?

Comment: Yeah, I derped. Thanks!